# splitting items of a list in python

Tags: python, list, listview

Hi I have a list,

```
 my_list=["one two","three four"]
```

my desired output is,

```
output_list=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

I tried the below code,

```
 my_list=" ".join(my_list)
 output_list=my_list.split()
 output_list,
 ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

It is working fine and I am getting my output, I hope, solution shorter than this will be available to achieve the same, Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple *nested list comprehension* should do quite nicely:

```
>>> [y for x in my_list for y in x.split()] 
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

---

Alternatively, use `itertools.chain`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain 
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, my_list)))
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

---

Interestingly, the `str.join` and consequent `str.split` that you suggested is the shortest version!

```
>>> " ".join(my_list).split()
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

---

### ᴘᴇʀғᴏʀᴍᴀɴᴄᴇ

```
my_list = ['foo bar' for _ in range(1000000)]
```

```
%timeit  [y for x in my_list for y in x.split()]
1 loop, best of 3: 554 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit list(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, my_list)))
1 loop, best of 3: 519 ms per loop  # yes, this surprised me too.
```

```
%timeit " ".join(my_list).split()
1 loop, best of 3: 200 ms per loop
```

Comment: plus one for itertools. Std lib has some gems

Comment: @Will indeed. However as a matter of personal preference I'd pick the list comp for readability ;-)

Comment: which will take less time?

Comment: your last method str.join I did in my question

Comment: @pyd yes, that's why I said "interestingly", because it was your proposed solution ;-) Let me just clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Another method by sum after split:

```
>>> sum(map(str.split, my_list),[])
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Comment: This is a possibility, yes, but it is excruciatingly slow, running into seconds when the other methods complete in a fraction of a second. Calling `sum` on lists is generally _very_ slow and should be avoided at all costs.